# "An error has occurred while executing python code" on QGIS startup (3.16.15)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, error

I had installed QGIS 3.16.15 through OSGeo installation package and began receiving this error message when starting QGIS. I completely uninstalled using the OSGeo advanced installation package, and reinstalled QGIS 3.16.15 using the standalone installer. Now I am receiving the same message. I can't interpret the error log successfully.

*Edit:* When I create a new user profile I receive no error messages. Should I be looking to clean out some saved profile directories?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script `DistantBear.py` does have a syntax error. As it is in your processing directory which is tied a profile, you receive an error when starting QGIS with this profile (`default`).

Solutions:

1. Fix the sytnax error in script `DistantBear.py`
2. Delete script `DistantBear.py` if unused